# Shouldn't @prev <> (@prev := Score) always be False?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `Scores`:

```
mysql> select * from Scores;
+------+-------+
| Id   | Score |
+------+-------+
|    1 |   3.5 |
|    2 |  3.65 |
|    3 |     4 |
|    4 |  3.85 |
|    5 |     4 |
|    6 |  3.65 |
+------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Execute the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    Score,
    @prev <> (@prev := Score) Res
FROM
    Scores,
    (SELECT @prev := -1) init
ORDER BY Score desc
```

get the result:

```
+-------+------+
| Score | Res  |
+-------+------+
|     4 |    1 |
|     4 |    0 |
|  3.85 |    1 |
|  3.65 |    1 |
|  3.65 |    0 |
|   3.5 |    1 |
+-------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice this part `@prev <> (@prev := Score)`, I assigned `Score` to `@prev`, so `@prev` should always equal `(@prev := Score)`(Just like `@prev` should always equal `@prev`), so the result of `@prev <> (@prev := Score)` should always be 0, why is there some 1s in the result set?

Comment: Check: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10b63c/1). Remember: `For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. ... the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.` See: [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html).

Answer (score 1):

The part `@prev <> (@prev := Score)` is parsed from left to right, so the first `@prev` still has its previous value, as this is intended, and only then it gets assigned the new value.